# Streamlines tangent to velocity vector

Tags: fluid-dynamics, definition

As from the title, I'm not too sure how they are related. Definition is that [streamlines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streamlines,_streaklines,_and_pathlines) are instantaneously tangential to the velocity vector of the field. Why would a streamline that shows direction be a tangent to the velocity?

Comment: I think that at an instant in time, the streamline would parallel to the velocity vector - would that be the same as the tangent?

Comment: I don't really get what you want to know?

Comment: @Bernhard I wanted to know why it was always tangent to the local velocity vector, but I understand now thanks. :)

Comment: I think it is simply how a streamline is defined.